# Why is grid-template-row not doing anything here?

Tags: css, css-grid

Here is my code:

```css
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 8vh, 90vh, 2vh;
      grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "main"
      "footer";
      text-align: center;
    }

    header {
      grid-area: header;
      /* min-height: 8vh; */
      background-color: green;
    }

    main {
      grid-area: main;
      /* min-height: 90vh; */
      background-color: blue;
    }

    footer {
      grid-area: footer;
      /* min-height: 2vh; */
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .list-box {
      width: 40%;
      margin: auto;
      background: orange;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
      <title>Ever-List</title>
    </head>
      <body class="container">
        <header>
          <div>
            <h1>Ever List</h1>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div class="list-box">
            <div>list1</div>
            <div>list2</div>
            <div>list3</div>
            <div>list4</div>
            <div>list5</div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <footer>© Maximilian Crosby</footer>
      <script href="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Why is it that when I use grid-template-row in this circumstance, my values are ignored and the grid hights are the minimum for the content?

If I add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to html, body CSS class the three rows are then equally divided into three sections of the window. Ignoring grid-template-row completely.

If I simply add my hight values into each item I get what I want but obviously I'd rather not do that.

I want to fill the window with my three rows and adjust each row height individually. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your grid-template-rows syntax is wrong. Please refer this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows

Comment: duuuu. So used to JS now I forgot to drop the commas. Thanks.